# NullReferenceException in Xamarin Firebase connection

Tags: .net, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, crud, nullreferenceexception

I am connecting my xamarin app to firebase, I created a full CRUD function and implemented it to my app.

I think I did everything right, but apperantly I did not because the UPDATE and DELETE functions does not really work..

I can Add items to the database but not UPDATE or DELETE them. When I try to uppdate or delete an item I get error on my update and delete functions.

This is my FirebaseHelper.cs that contains all the CRUD functions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Database.Query;

namespace ElseWareApp.Models
{
    public class FirebaseHelper
    {
        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://urldb-4fcca-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
        {

            return (await firebase
                .Child("Persons")
                .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
            {
                Name = item.Object.Name,
                PersonId = item.Object.PersonId
            }).ToList();
        }

        public async Task AddPerson(int personId, string name)
        {

            await firebase
                .Child("Persons")
                .PostAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name });
        }

        public async Task<Person> GetPerson(int personId)
        {
            var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
            await firebase
                .Child("Persons")
                .OnceAsync<Person>();
            return allPersons.Where(a => a.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public async Task UpdatePerson(int personId, string name)
        {
            var toUpdatePerson = (await firebase
                .Child("Persons")
                .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();

            await firebase
                .Child("Persons")
                .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
                .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name });
        }

        public async Task DeletePerson(int personId)
        {
            var toDeletePerson = (await firebase
                .Child("Persons")
                .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();
    

    await firebase.Child("Persons").Child(toDeletePerson.Key).DeleteAsync();

    }
  }
}
```

The error I get is in **DeletePerson** class is in the last line:  `**await firebase.Child("Persons").Child(toDeletePerson.Key).DeleteAsync();**`

The error I get in UpdatePerson class is also in last line

```
 await firebase
                    .Child("Persons")
                    .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
                    .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name });
```

Both functions gives me this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Hope someone can help!

Comment: this is the same issue as your previous question.  You have a null object, you need to figure out which one it is, then why, then fix it.  You need to use the debugger to figure which object(s) in that statement is null.

Comment: @Jason and what do I do when I find that object?

Comment: figure out why it's null

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Jason, but the reason I ask the question here is obvios, I dont know how to find which one is null

Comment: in the debugger, but a breakpoint on that line, hover over each element to check the value, and figure out which one is returning null.  Or if you don't know how to use the debugger, break the compound statement up into multiple lines and `Console.WriteLine` the value of each one to figure out which one causes the break

Comment: @Jason I found it! its the variable toDeletePerson which returns null in the DeletePerson Method. What can be done next?

Comment: that means your query did not return a match.  You should test for null before calling the delete

Comment: @Jason  you mean I should comment out the whole delete function? In that case how can I test null ?

Comment: where did I say to comment anything?

Comment: I didn't understand, but what do you mean excatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this query is returning null

```
var toDeletePerson = (await firebase
            .Child("Persons")
            .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();
```

then this will throw a null reference exception

```
await firebase.Child("Persons").Child(toDeletePerson.Key).DeleteAsync();
```

you should test for null first

```
if (toDeletePerson != null) 
{
    await firebase.Child("Persons").Child(toDeletePerson.Key).DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: When I debug, the personId = 0, which is weird because I dont have 0 in my db

Comment: then you should debug that - where does that value get passed from originally?  How is it getting set to an invalid value?  etc...